# Can someone help me find where these Ibn Taymiyyah quotes come from?

Tags: quran, hadith, islamic-scholar

There are two quotes from Ibn Taymiyyah that have been floating around the internet for a while.

One supposedly comes from a work known as "Sheik of the Muslims" (vol. XII, p. 101). The problem is I have not been able to find this book anywhere.

"The companions of Muhammad had never used the diacritical points or the vocalization for the Qur’an. For each word, there were two readings—either to use (for instance) ‘ya’ or ‘tah’ in such words as ‘they do’ or ‘you do’. The companion did not forbid one of the readings in favor of the other, then some successor of the companions began to use the diacritical points and vocalization for the Qur’an."

Another quote from page 578 and 586 of the book

"The companions (Muhammad’s friends) did not vocalize or provide diacritical points for the letters of the Qur’anic copies which they wrote, but later during the last part of the companions’ era, when reading errors came into being, they began to provide diacritical points for the copies of the Qur’an and to vocalize them. This was admissible by the authority of the majority of the scholars, though some of them disliked it. The truth is, it should not be disliked because the situation necessitated it, and the diacritical points distinguish the letters from each other while vocalization explains the grammatical inflection."

Could someone provide me with the source and quote in Arabic? Thanks.

Comment: Ibn Tayymiyah is often referred to as Sheikh Al-Islam not of Muslims. Secondly what he or whomever said is correct and well known as the Arabic script was not yet refined so letters sucg as ب، ت، ن، ث had no dots abd looked similar, the same applies to many other letters. Ibn Tayymiyah AFAIK was not an expert ib qur'an sciences. I rather guess that this was quoted in his majmo' al-Fatawa.